# convert short youtube url to full url

Tags: php, regex, youtube

Hi all i am looking for a simple way to check if a string equals an url like this:

```
http://youtu.be/WWQZ046NeUA
```

To convert it to a proper youtube url like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWQZ046NeUA
```

If not to leave it alone, what's the simplest way to do it in php?

Comment: Have you tried anything? I see you tagged regex, so you have an idea of what you could use to validate the url.

Comment: have you tried googling? the first URL that I hit is explaining http://blog.absolutedisaster.co.uk/php-convert-youtube-urls-to-youtubecom/

Answer (score 6):

You can use this `preg_replace` call:

```
$u = 'http://youtu.be/WWQZ046NeUA';
$r = preg_replace('~^https?://youtu\.be/([a-z\d]+)$~i', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1', $u);
```

Comment: This doesn't cater for youtube urls that have - or _ in their code

Comment: We can use `~^https?://youtu\.be/([\w-]+)$~i` for that case.

Answer (score 5):

`str_replace` should work wonders.

```
$url = ''; //url you're checking
$ytshorturl = 'youtu.be/';
$ytlongurl = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
if (strpos($url,$yturl) !== false) {
    $url = str_replace($ytshorturl, $ytlongurl, $url);
}
```